# C++ - when is object destroyed

Tags: c++, rvalue

I have a class which serves as handle to a temporary directory used for testing. It is used like this:

```
{
    TestArea ta("name_of_test");
    ta.call_method( );
    test_stuff( );
    ...
}
```

when the closing `}` is reached the `ta` variable goes out of scope and everything is cleaned up. In many cases I do not need to call any of the `TestArea` methods - and this sufficient:

```
{
    TestArea("name_of_test");
    test_stuff();
}
```

i.e. there is no lvalue associated with the `TestArea` instance. Now my question is - when will the `TestArea` destructor be called in this place? The latter code actually seems to work - but I am slightly uneasy about it.

Comment: Don't be uneasy, RAII objects are usually designed that way and work fine.

Comment: Related pitfall, watch out for `TestArea(x);`   , this is actually a declaration  (same as `TestArea x;` with redundant parentheses)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With

```
TestArea("name_of_test");
```

you create a *temporary* object, and that temporary object will be destructed *immediately*.

So once the expression where it was used is over, then the object no longer exists.

Comment: Where "immediately" means "after the object is constructed, then it will be destructed before the next statement is begun".  Sometimes that's okay, if the action desired is all in the constructor or destructor or both, and doesn't need to be extant beyond that one statement.

Comment: Thank you - I though it was like that; so the fact it did seem to work also with the temporary object was just pure "lucky" undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

In both cases, an object is created and is destructed when it goes out of scope.

In the first case, a named object `ta` is created that goes out of scope when the nearest closing `}` is reached.

In the second case, an *unnamed temporary* object is created that goes out of scope when the terminating `;` at the end of the statement is reached. The same is true for any temporary object created within the same statement. For example:

```
doSomething(T1(), T2(), T3());
```

This creates 3 temporary objects that all remain in scope until the terminating `;` is reached.